# Best method for sending app mail from an Ubuntu 14.4 machine with ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, ubuntu-14.04

This is more a semantic questions than anything else.

I have setup a web app on an Ubuntu 14.4 server. I need my app to send mail. Now in the past I have simply installed postfix however, I am thinking of simply connecting to an SMPT server hosted elsewhere.

I am struggling somewhat to get this right with Ubuntu and ZF2.

Essentially my mail code is as follows:

```
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;

$mailMessage = new MailMessage();
$mailMessage->setBody($mimeBody);
$mailMessage->setEncoding($this->mailEncoding);
$mailMessage->setFrom($this->mailFrom);
$mailMessage->setTo($this->mailTo);
$mailMessage->setSubject($this->mailSubject);

$options = new SmtpOptions();
$transport = new Smtp($options);
$transport->send($mailMessage);
```

At what point in this code do I set the SMTP settings? And how should this be done?

I tried doing something like this:

```
    $options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
        'name' => 'localhost',
        'host' => '12.12.12.1.2',
        'port' => 25,
    ));
```

**The error I get is this:**

Could not read from 12.12.12.1.2

**I then updated this to:**

```
$options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
        'name' => 'mail.example.com',
        'host' => '2.12.12.1.21',
        'port' => 25,
    ));
```

This got rid of the error... but no email is arriving.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to re-write postfix (or sendmail etc.) in your application! Remember, you will need to handle all error cases, such as the SMTP server being busy, you'll need to deal with queueing, retries, and all kinds of horrible things. Really, your old way is ideal: pass it to the local MTA, and be done with it.

Trust me, I see this all the time: lost e-mail, because the application tried to do something that is not really the application's job. Do what you do best, and leave e-mail to the e-mail folks, which they do best.

And apologies if I seem grouchy or pushy, and I'm not really answering your question - my job involves mail servers, and I see this happening all to often :-)

Comment: Good advice. I got the SMTP method working however the mail ended up in  the end users spam box. Moving to PostFix, the mail arrived as expected.